# View unable to refresh in android lollipop

Tags: android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop

I am setting the adapter(extending baseadapter) to listview in post execute of asynctask but the view is not showing any items. 
I am getting all the values.Its a problem only in android lollypop, prior to that its working fine. I am unable to find the problem. Please help

```
in postexecute
System.out.println(agendas.size());//getting value as 1

    viewadapter = new Viewadapter(Agenda.this);
                        lv.setAdapter(viewadapter);

lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println(lv.getVisibility());//getting 0
                System.out.println(lv.getAdapter().getCount());//getting count as 1
```

in viewadapter

```
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return agendas.size();

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return agendas.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                 ViewGroup parent) {
                //inflating the layout
                //assgning values
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem and it seems that if getView returns convertView, it does not get redrawn. If I force getView to create a new View object to return every time, then it draws like it did before Lollipop.